# htaccessの設定について

Tags: angularjs, cakephp, apache, .htaccess

htaccessの設定（書き方）についてご教授ください。

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

↑こちらはcakephpのwebrootに置かれているhtaccessです。

これに追加で以下のような設定を書き込みたいと思っております。
cakephpの仕様はそのまま必要なので、URLが「www.test.com/index.html」じゃない場合は「www.test.com/index.html」にリダイレクトしたいです。

■リダイレクト対象URL
www.test.com/index.html#customer
www.test.com/index.html#employee
www.test.com/index.html#employee?id=test
など

■リダイレクトしないURL
www.test.com/index.html
www.test.com/index.html#auth
www.test.com/index.html#auth?id=test&password=test
www.test.com/index.html#special

view周りをangularjsを使っていて、このようなURLになっております。

以上、よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: コードはマークダウンでハイライトできます。コードを選択して`｛｝`ボタンを押下で自動でマークダウン化することも出来ます。

Comment: ”URLが「www.test.com/index.html」じゃない場合は「www.test.com/index.html」にリダイレクトしたい” とその後の例示の整合性がとれていないようですが、URLハッシュ部によってリダイレクトを制御したいということでしょうか。

Comment: もしかして、リダイレクト対象URLの場合はCakePHPへ処理を流して、それ以外はそのままにしたいということでしょうか。